# How change the selected value in drop-down list

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to change the selected value in the drop-down list when the page is loaded using the value in the database.

I have implemented a drop-down list using database values. It works fine. There is a column name `con_s` and it has only one `1` value and all others are `0`. I have assigned it to `name` attribute in `<option>`. I want to `selected` data which has `1` in column `con_s` when the page is loaded.

I have no idea how can I do this. I have mentioned my tried code below.

Tried code:

```
 <select id="cur_rate" @change="onChange()">
    {{#each currencies}}
      <option value="{{this.rate}}" name="{{this.con_s}}" selected>{{this.currency}}</option>
    {{/each}}
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [build-in helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if) `if` condition to provide the selected option. you can try like this code snippet. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fsh0y83/)

```html
   <select id="cur_rate">
    {{#each currencies}}
      <option value="{{this.rate}}" name="{{this.con_s}}" {{#if this.con_s}}selected{{/if}}>{{this.rate}}</option>
    {{/each}}
 </select>
```